# Using jquery Isotope library with ember-cli

Tags: jquery-isotope, ember-cli

I'm trying to use Isotope library in my app created with ember-cli;
I've created a component that activates it:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.next(this, function(){
            var $container = $('#container');
            // init
            $('#container').isotope({
                // options
                itemSelector: '.item',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Running this I get an error saying "undefined is not a function" relatively to isotope call.

Trying to replicate this error outside ember-cli, I found that it occurs when the isotope script is included before jquery;

in ember-cli I import the isotope script using app.import in the Brocfile:

```
app.import('bower_components/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd.js');
```

Have someone used succesfully jquery Isotope with ember-cli?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'll add it so maybe it'll help someone....

install via bower

```
    bower install isotope --save
```

or via npm

```
    npm install isotope-layout
```

Add this to the ember-cli-build.js file

```
    app.import('bower_components/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js');
```

Create a new component

```
    ember g component isotope-grid
```

Add this to the component.js inside the Component.extend

```
classNames: ['isotope-grid'],

didInsertElement() {
  this.$().isotope({
    itemSelector: 'li',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });
}
```

Now, as long as the grid is a ul with a class of isotope-grid, you should be in business.